# Excel formula to look up and pick a value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a need to place an excel formula in Column-D. I am trying my best explain the need since I am not sure about how to explain this need.

The formula should search the Column-C value in the Column-A. When a match is found the corresponding Column B value should be placed in D.

Here is an axample of how the result should be.

```
Column-A Column-B Column-C Column-D
A        2        C         =Formula should fill 9 over here.
B        5        A         =Formula should fill 2 here.
C        9
D        12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLookup should do what you need.  Try

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, A$1:B$4, 2)
```

EDIT: Thinking about it, you'll want $ signs around your lookup array as it won't change when you copy the formula down.